# What is argument code in FieldError object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following lines in my code. I am validating captcha in a JSP form.
I don't understand the meaning of all arguments passed in the `FieldError` object.

```
if (!reCaptchaResponse.isValid()) {
    FieldError fieldError = new FieldError("CaptchaObj", "captcha",
            uresponse, false, new String[] { "badCptcha.CaptchaObj.captcha" },
            null, "Please, Try Again ");
    result.addError(fieldError);
}
```

HERE result variable is of type `BindingResult`.

I want the exact meaning of each argument in the constructor of the `FieldError` object and especially for the **code argument** in the constructor which of type `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest reading the API documentation for field error found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/).

It mentions the following parameters for this constructor:

```
Parameters:
    objectName - the name of the affected object
    field - the affected field of the object
    rejectedValue - the rejected field value
    bindingFailure - whether this error represents a binding failure (like a type mismatch); else, it is a validation failure
    codes - the codes to be used to resolve this message
    arguments - the array of arguments to be used to resolve this message
    defaultMessage - the default message to be used to resolve this message
```

One of the most important parameters is the codes parameter, which contains a code that will be searched for within your message sources.  If found the message matching this code will be displayed.  Message sources can take arguments, so a Message Source can contain an entry like:

```
typeMismatch.startDate={0} is an invalid date. Use format DD/MM/YYYY.
```

In this case the code would be `typeMismatch.startDate` and the message corresponding with this code will display the first argument followed by the message.  The `{0}` piece of the message indicates that it should display the first argument.  These arguments are provided by the 6th parameter in the constructor, which in your example is null.

Comment: @HarshadDeshmukh I was getting to that!  I described two of the more important parameters, hope this helps.